# Cambiar variable con un botón en Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy haciendo una calculadora básica en Python con Tkinter pero no encuentro la forma de que al presionar el botón se cambia la variable a concatenar, por ejemplo:
x=0
si se aprieta el botón 1 que se cambie el valor de la variable x a 1.
Lo que no quiero es tener que crear una función para cada botón, y si mando a llamar la función mandando el valor no me funciona.

así lo tengo:

```
def concatenacion(x):
    aux = texto.get()
    concatenado = aux + str(1)
    texto.set(concatenado)

framePantalla = Tkinter.Frame(ventana, width=100, height=200)
framePantalla.pack(side=Tkinter.TOP)
frame = Tkinter.Frame(ventana, width=300, height=400)
frame.pack(side=Tkinter.BOTTOM)


texto = Tkinter.StringVar()

inPantalla = Tkinter.Entry(framePantalla,
                           width=18,
                           font="Courier 20",
                           textvariable=texto
                           ).grid(row=1)

button1 = Tkinter.Button(frame,
                         text="1",
                         width=8,
                         height=2,
                         relief=Tkinter.GROOVE,
                         font="Courier  8 bold",
                         background="gray",
                         command=concatenacion(1)
                         ).grid(column=1, row=1)
```

Comment: Bienvenido a "SO en Español", José. Por favor, completa el código con las líneas que faltan para que funcione y podamos reproducir el problema que tienes. En concreto, no se indica cómo creas la variable `ventana` ni figura cómo importas el módulo `Tkinter` ni el resto de constantes que usas. (Revisa la ayuda sobre [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo el código de ejemplo, `command=concatenacion(1)` no hace nada porque la *evaluación* de `concatenacion(1)` es `None` (retorno por defecto de una función cuando no tiene un retorno explícito).

Un modo de que funcione sería pasando la llamada como *función lambda*:

```
button1 = Tkinter.Button(frame,
    ...
    command=lambda : concatenacion(1)
    ...
```

Pero mi método preferido para estos casos es usar *llamadas parciales* ([*"currificación"*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currificaci%C3%B3n)) donde puedes fijar el valor de algunos de los argumentos de una función:

```
from functools import partial

button1 = Tkinter.Button(frame,
    ...
    command=partial(concatenacion, 1)
    ...
```

Con este uso, se pueden crear fácilmente los botones de modo programático:

```
buttons = [ Tkinter.Button(frame,
                           text=str(r+c)
                           ...
                           command=partial(concatenacion, r+c)
                           ...).grid(column=c, row=r)
                  for r in range(1,4)
                    for c in range(1,4)
          ]
```